# Selecting all products and conditionally changing a field

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query to select my products from the stock table :

```
   SELECT s.ProductCode,s.stock,s.default_sales_cost,s.nextstockdate,cp.price custom_price FROM standsafe.stock s
join custom_prices cp on cp.productcode = s.ProductCode
where cp.customerid = 'A4909984'
```

The stock table has a "default_sales_cost" column which is the cost of the product.

I want to select all the stock, but if there is an entry in the custom_price table (currently there is one for the customer A4909984), i want the price to be the price that is in the custom price table and not what is in stock. (basically if there is an entry in the custom price table then it should override the stocks price).

Currently the only results i from the query is one stock entry because i believe the join is incorrect, can someone please assist?

Comment: use case condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `COALESCE`. The join would have to be an outer join, so you get the product, no matter whether there exists a custom_prices record or not.

```
SELECT 
  s.ProductCode,
  s.stock,
  COALESCE(cp.price, s.default_sales_cost) as cost,
  s.nextstockdate
FROM standsafe.stock s
LEFT OUTER JOIN custom_prices cp ON  cp.productcode = s.productcode
                                 AND cp.customerid = 'A4909984';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression like

```
case when cp.default_sales_cost is not null then cp.default_sales_cost else s.default_sales_cost end
```

(OR) better yet use `COALESCE()` like

```
COALESCE(cp.default_sales_cost, s.default_sales_cost)
```